# Webstorm autocomplete not working with project files

Tags: node.js, autocomplete, webstorm

I decided to try Webstorm, mainly for the autocomplete feature, but I've got an issue with it.
I require a .js file of my project(Which in this case is a driver to communicate with my Database) but the autocomplete is not working properly:

```
 var db = require('../../config/database');

 var Validator = {};

 Validator.isAKnownUserId = function (user_id) {

     var query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?';
     db.

};
```

The databse.js file :

```
var cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');

// Client connecting to the keyspace used by the application
var client = new cassandra.Client ({
     keyspace: keyspace,
     contactPoints: ['127.0.0.1']
});

module.exports = client;
```

As you can see nothing special. But for example the "execute" function that is available with the cassandra.Client is not autocompletes in my **validator.js** file when it is in the **database.js** file.

Furthermore, if I replace

```
var db = require('../../config/database');
```

with

```
var db;
db = require('../../config/database');
```

or

```
var db = new require('../../config/database');
```

then the autocomplete is working correctly in my file.

Can someone help me figure out this behavior and how to get a proper autocomplete ?

Thanks in advance